# Take ownership to mutable reference in unsafe block

Tags: c, rust, struct

I am wrapping an existing C library in Rust. The C library has a public structure like this:

```c
struct {
   int flag;
   float * buffer;
} data_type;
```

and it has an API like:

```c
void init_struct(struct data_type * data, int flag, float * buffer);
void run(struct data_type * data, const float * input_data, float * output_data);
```

i.e. a typical C usage of this would be something like:

```c
int main {
    int flag = 32;
    float * buffer = malloc( 1000*sizeof * float);
    {
        struct data_type data;
        init_struct(&data, flag, buffer);
        float input_data[64];
        float ouput_data[64];
        ... 
        ...
        run(&data, input_data, output_data);
        ...
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

In rust I want to create a (tuple) struct wrapping the C `struct data_type`. The following roughly works:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct data_type {
    flag : u32,
    buffer : *mut f32,
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn init_struct(
        S: *mut data_struct,
        input_data: i32,
        buffer: *mut f32);

    pub fn run(
        S: *const data_struct,
        input_data: *const f32,
        output_data: *mut f32);
}

pub struct Data(data_type);

impl Data {
    pub fn new(flag: u32, buffer: &mut [f32]) -> Self {
        let mut data = MaybeUninit::<data_type>::uninit();
        unsafe {
            init_struct(data.as_mut_ptr(), flag, buffer.as_mut_ptr());
            FloatFIR(data.assume_init())
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self, input: &[f32], output: &mut [f32]) {
        // ....
    }

}
```

However, as you can see from the code, I pass a mutable reference/pointer down to the C api, i.e. I would like the Rust borrow checker to ensure that the buffer can only be used in *one* `Data` instance at a time; but I guess that since the `buffer` is tucked away to C inside an unsafe section the borrow checker does not see that the `Data` instance holds on the buffer, and after `Data::new()` has returned it is happy to pass out new mutable refernces to the buffer?

Can I in some way explicitly say in the `Data::new()`, that for it's entire lifetime the `Data` instance will hold on to the supplied mutable buffer argument?

The code as posted is a simplified version and not Copy & Paste, i.e. it will probably not compile. However I hope it illustrates the problem/question?

Comment: nit: for FFI on the Rust side, use [`std::ffi::c_int`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/type.c_int.html) instead of `i32`, likewise with `float`, etc

Comment: The code you posted also has a few errors: `float32_t` is not a thing in Rust, `&mut f[32]` occurs in a couple places.

Comment: One easy way to accomplish what you want is to allocate `buffer` on the Rust side and store a `&mut [c_float]` in `Data`.

Comment: Is `data_struct` a typo of `data_type`? And `FloatFIR` a remaining original name for `Data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tie the lifetime of the borrow to the `Data` struct somehow, one possible solution is to just store the mutable slice alongside the C ffi struct:

```rust
pub struct Data<'a>(data_type, &'a mut [f32]);

impl<'a> Data<'a> {
    pub fn new(flag: u32, buffer: &'a mut [f32]) -> Self {
        let mut data = MaybeUninit::<data_type>::uninit();
        Data(
            unsafe {
                init_struct(data.as_mut_ptr(), flag, buffer.as_mut_ptr());
                data.assume_init()
            },
            buffer,
        )
    }
}
```

If you need to avoid the overhead of that pointer + length you can use [`std::marker::PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) instead:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
pub struct Data<'a>(data_type, PhantomData<&'a mut [f32]>);

impl<'a> Data<'a> {
    pub fn new(flag: u32, buffer: &'a mut [f32]) -> Self {
        let mut data = MaybeUninit::<data_type>::uninit();
        Data(
            unsafe {
                init_struct(data.as_mut_ptr(), flag, buffer.as_mut_ptr());
                data.assume_init()
            },
            PhantomData,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the first one is undefined behavior due to storing a `&mut` that is accessed from or written by another pointer. `PhantomData` is the usual way to solve this and should be used here.

Comment: By your reasoning `as_mut_ptr` would be a pretty useless function, but you have a point, you have to be careful with that pointer and the reference.